# How I can copy google document and share access to email?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

There is a template on google doc.
We want to copy it and provide access by mail.
Maybe there are those who know how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer?

Unfortunately, the copy of file and the modification of permissions of the file cannot be done with Google Docs API. In this case, it is required to use Drive API. The flow for achieving your goal is as follows.

### 1. Copy of Google Document file.

In this case, the method of "Files: copy" of Drive API v3 is used. The endpoint and sample request body is as follows. The file ID is the file ID of the template Google Document file.

#### Endpoint:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/copy
```

#### Sample request body:

```
{"name": "sample name"}
```

#### Sample curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/copy'
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"name":"sample name"}' \
  --compressed
```

- When the file is copied, the file ID of the copied file is returned.

### 2. Create permissions.

In this case, the method of "Permissions: create" of Drive API v3 is used. The endpoint and sample request body is as follows. The file ID is the file ID of copied file.

#### Endpoint:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions
```

#### Sample request body:

```
{
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "###"
}
```

#### Sample curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"role":"writer","type":"user","emailAddress":"###"}' \
  --compressed
```

- In this case, the user of email address `###` has the permission of the writer for the file.

### Note:

- In above flow, the access token is required. Unfortunately, the API key cannot be used for this situation. Please be careful this.
- If you want to modify the copied Google Document using API, please use Google Docs API.

### References:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)
- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)